# Rustでネットワークライブラリを使う時に標準ライブラリを使えば異なるOS間でもコードを使いまわせますか？

Tags: rust

Rustでネットワークライブラリを使う時に標準ライブラリを使えば異なるOS間でもコードを使いまわせますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

標準ライブラリ内の[`std::net`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/)（IPv4/IPv6上でのTCP/UDPプロトコルを扱うライブラリ群）のみを使うコード・ライブラリであればRustがTier1としてサポートしているプラットフォーム全てで動きますので、異なるOS間でもコードを使いまわせます。Tier2、Tier3でも動く可能性は高いですが、Rustデベロッパーは正しく動作することは保証していません。
コンパイラ・標準ライブラリ・cargoそれぞれのサポート状況は[こちら](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html)で確認できますが、参考までに2016/11/13現在のTier1プラットフォーム（上記3つをすべてサポート）は以下の通りです。

> i686-apple-darwin = 32-bit OSX (10.7+, Lion+)
>   i686-pc-windows-gnu = 32-bit MinGW (Windows 7+)
>   i686-pc-windows-msvc = 32-bit MSVC (Windows 7+)
>   i686-unknown-linux-gnu = 32-bit Linux (2.6.18+)
>   x86_64-apple-darwin = 64-bit OSX (10.7+, Lion+)
>   x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = 64-bit MinGW (Windows 7+)
>   x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = 64-bit MSVC (Windows 7+)
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = 64-bit Linux (2.6.18+)

Comment: ありがとうございます。